# return type as function in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, types

I have a class named `ValidatorHelper` :

```
class ValidatorHelper
{
   public name:string
   public value: any
  
  constructor(name:string,vlaue:any)
  {
     this.name = name
     this.value = value
  }
  toString(): string
  {
     return '"name":"' + this.name + '","value":"' + this.value + '"'
  }
 }
```

and a class named `ValidatorBuilder`

```
 class ValidatorBuilder {
  private validators: ValidatorHelper[] = [];
  public Build(): (name: string, value: string) => string[] {
    //how can I build the return type with this.validators
  }
  public required(): ValidatorBuilder {
    this.validators.push(new ValidatorHelper('required', true));
    return this;
  }
  public pattern(pattern: string | RegExp): ValidatorBuilder {
    this.validators.push(new ValidatorHelper('pattern', pattern));
    return this;
  }
```

Is there any way to build the return type of `Build` function with `validators`?

Or even better ideas for my `ValidatorBuilder`

Comment: You can create a interface same as properties present in build and use the interface as a return type.

Comment: What exactly should `Build()` return?

Comment: @Christian It sould return a function with the `name` and `value` as input and return all the items in `validators` array base on the `toString` function

Comment: So you would like `Build` to return both a function and an array?

Comment: @Christian no, just the function, the return parameter of function would be based on the array

Comment: Should the resulting array returned by this function contain all items in `this.validators` that matches the arguments of the function? I.e. the items in `this.validators` that has the same `name` and/or `value` is the name/value passed to the function?

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss the point of validation. Validation checks one element and returns a boolean for the result. You can specify this by an interface.

```
interface Validator {
  validate: (value: any) => boolean;
}
```

Now you have different kind of validations. In your example Required and Pattern. Let's define those.

```
class RequiredValidator implements Validator {
  validate(value: any) {
    return !!value;
  }
}

class RequiredValidator implements Validator {

  regularExpression: RegExp;

  constructor(regularExpression: string | RegExp) {
    this.regularExpression = typeof regularExpression === 'string' ? new RegExp(regularExpression) : regularExpression;
  }

  validate(value: string): boolean {
    return this.regularExpression.test(value);
  }
}
```

Now you can add your builder. The build step also needs to return a validator or a validate function. After all this is nothing else but a chaining of all stored validations.

```
class ValidatorBuilder {
  private validators: Validator[] = [];

  public required(): ValidatorBuilder {
    this.validators.push(new RequiredValidator());
    return this;
  }

  public pattern(pattern: string | RegExp): ValidatorBuilder {
    this.validators.push(new PatternValidator(pattern));
    return this;
  }

  public build(): Validator {
    return {
      validate: (value: any) => this.validators.every(validator => validator.validate(value)),
    };   
  }
}
```

Test it:

```
const myValidator: Validator = new ValidatorBuilder().required().pattern('[\\d]+').build();

console.log('required fails', myValidator.validate(null));
console.log('pattern fails', myValidator.validate('abc'));
console.log('all ok',  myValidator.validate('123'));
```

See: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-sb5yny

**Please note, that this example still have some bugs. You can easily run into misbehavior, when you pass for example an object. This simple quick and dirty example is only for demonstration.**